# How to create a custom form element for file upload in Sitecore 9 Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am trying to create a simple file upload through Sitecore Forms. I thought to create a custom form element to do this, but am unsure of how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I would wait for next update and you will have it OOTB IMHO. I think that this functionality was omitted initially just to make Sitecore Forms working nicely in Sitecore 9 and they will add more and more functionality to pair it with WFFM module which will be deprecated for next major version

2) You can install WFFM for Sitecore 9 which has this functionality but be aware that WFFM will be deprecated in next major version of Sitecore

3) If you really need it now with Sitecore Forms, you should create a new custom form element "FileUpload".

You should follow this [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_form_element) to achieve this.

You can find lot of articles on how to do fileupload with ASP.NET MVC. If you combine them with Sitecore documentation about creating custom form element, you will achieve your goal.

I would also take a look and disassemble code of WFFM to see how it's working there and you can inspire your code based on that.